# How to use classifiers used by cross_validation_scores

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I am attempting to train a cross validated SVM model (for a school project). Given `X` and `y`, when I call

```
clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=4)
```

`scores` is set to an array as expected, but I want to be able to call `clf.predict(test_x)` but when I do it throws an exception with the message `This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.` (I wish it would return something like `[scores, predictor]` or maybe a *`CrossValidationPredictor`* that has a `predict` method, but that is not the case.)

Of course, I can call `classifier = clf.fit(X, y)` but that doesn't give me a cross validated SVM predictor, how do I get a cross validated predictor that I can use to—you know—predict?

Comment: You want `GridSearchCV`, with parameter `refit=True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course, I can call `classifier = clf.fit(X, y)` but that doesn't give me a cross validated SVM predictor, how do I get a cross validated predictor that I can use to—you know—predict?

`clf.fit(X, y)` is exactly what you should do.

There is no such thing as a cross validated *predictor* because cross-validation is not a method for training a predictor but, well, for *validating* a type of predictor. Let me quote the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)):

> Cross-validation [...] is any of various similar model validation techniques for assessing how the results of a statistical analysis will generalize to an independent data set.

(Statistical analysis, here, includes prediction models such as regressors or classifiers.)

The question that cross validation answers is "*How well will my classifier perform later when I apply it to data I don't have yet?*". Usually you try to cross validate different classifiers or hyperparameters and then select the one with the highest score, which is the one that is expected to generalize best to unseen data.

Finally you train the classifier on the full data set, because you want to deploy the best possible classifer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look a grid-search:

> Grid-search
>
> scikit-learn provides an object that, given data, computes the score
>   during the fit of an estimator on a parameter grid and chooses the
>   parameters to maximize the cross-validation score. This object takes
>   an estimator during the construction and exposes an estimator API

Example:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
>>> Cs = np.logspace(-6, -1, 10)
>>> clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc, param_grid=dict(C=Cs),
...                    n_jobs=-1)
>>> clf.fit(X_digits[:1000], y_digits[:1000])        
GridSearchCV(cv=None,...
>>> clf.best_score_                                  
0.925...
>>> clf.best_estimator_.C                            
0.0077...

>>> # Prediction performance on test set is not as good as on train set
>>> clf.score(X_digits[1000:], y_digits[1000:])
```

Here is the site for checking it: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html

Comment: Although the question does not indicate they want to do a parameter search, this may well be what they really need :)  (Note though, that under the hood `GridSearchCV` actually does a refit on the whole dataset, similar to `clf.fit(X, y)`.)